# how to migrate automate from aws rds datbase (MySql) to Azure Database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, azure

is there an automatic tool that could migrate from Aws rds to Azure Database for MySQL ? i know how to dump and restore standard swql server but i would like to have a well known tool maybe build in Azure  that is already does that